# WxPython GUI programming.

Tags: python, wxpython

So my problem is, i need to make a GUI in wxpython that calculates the price of the hamburger. each extra ingredient is 1.55 and the small price is 1.55 and medium is 1.55 plus 1.55 and so on. My question is this: How can i assign the radiobuttons, like if i wanted to do this:
if radiobutton1 is selected:
           do this

and same with the number of checked boxes. heres my script so far.

```
import wx

class Window(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(400, 250))
        self.title = title
        self.initGUI()

    def initGUI(self):
        # Set up the widgets for the GUI
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.amount = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, 'Ingredients = 0', pos=(10, 10))

        #                      Parent ID  Value         Position (Height, Width)
        self.cb1 = wx.CheckBox(panel, -1, 'Extra Patty', (10, 30))
        self.cb2 = wx.CheckBox(panel, -1, 'Cheese', (10, 50))
        self.cb3 = wx.CheckBox(panel, -1, 'Onions', (10, 70))
        self.cb4 = wx.CheckBox(panel, -1, 'Mushrooms', (10,90))
        # Register an event for each checkbox.
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHECKBOX, self.toggleIngredients, self.cb1)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHECKBOX, self.toggleIngredients, self.cb2)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHECKBOX, self.toggleIngredients, self.cb3)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHECKBOX, self.toggleIngredients, self.cb4)
    self.rb1 = wx.RadioButton(panel, -1, 'Small', (200,30))
    self.rb2 = wx.RadioButton(panel, -1, 'Medium', (200,50))
    self.rb3 = wx.RadioButton(panel, -1, 'Large', (200, 70))

        self.Show()
        self.Centre()

    def toggleIngredients(self, event):
        self.ingredients = 0
        for cb in (self.cb1, self.cb2, self.cb3, self.cb4):
            if cb.IsChecked():
                self.ingredients += 1
        self.amount.SetLabel('Ingredients = ' + str(self.ingredients))

    if self.amount.SetLabel == '1':
        ing = 1
    if self.amount.SetLabel == '2':
        ing = 2
    if self.amount.SetLabel == '3':
        ing = 3
    if self.amount.SetLabel == '4':
        ing = 4


app = wx.App(False)
window = Window(None, 'CheckBox Example')
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: i also dont know how to make a text box type thing where the total cost shows up. im a noob at wxpython

Comment: Have you tried a [WxPython tutorial](http://www.google.com/search?q=wxpython+tutorial)?

Answer (score 0):

see UpdateCost method

```
    import wx

class Window(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(400, 250))
        self.title = title
        self.initGUI()

    def initGUI(self):
        # Set up the widgets for the GUI
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.amount = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, 'Ingredients = 0', pos=(10, 10))

        #                      Parent ID  Value         Position (Height, Width)
        self.cbs = [
                    wx.CheckBox(panel, -1, 'Extra Patty', (10, 30)),
                    wx.CheckBox(panel, -1, 'Cheese', (10, 50)),
                    wx.CheckBox(panel, -1, 'Onions', (10, 70)),
                    wx.CheckBox(panel, -1, 'Mushrooms', (10,90))
                    ]
        # Register an event for each checkbox.
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHECKBOX, self.toggleIngredients)
        self.radios = [
                    wx.RadioButton(panel, -1, 'Small', (200,30)),
                    wx.RadioButton(panel, -1, 'Medium', (200,50)),
                    wx.RadioButton(panel, -1, 'Large', (200, 70))
                    ]
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_RADIOBUTTON,self.toggleIngredients)
        self.Show()
        self.Centre()
    def UpdateCost(self):
        costs = {"Small":1.55,"Medium":3.10,"Large":4.65}
        base_cost = 0.00
        for r in self.radios:
            if r.GetValue():
                base_cost = costs[r.GetLabel()]
        additional_costs = sum([1.5 for x in self.cbs if x.GetValue()])
        self.amount.SetLabel("$%0.2f"%(base_cost+additional_costs))
    def toggleIngredients(self, event):
        self.UpdateCost()


app = wx.App(False)
window = Window(None, 'CheckBox Example')
app.MainLoop()
```

I really could have just bound the events directly to it... but I wanted to leave most of your code intact